# Highlight a variable and see other instances highlighted in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, when you highlight a variable in your code, other places that variable is used in the code is highlighted. I'm trying to change the color of this highlighting.

As you can see in the image, I highlight var on line 78, and it is therefore highlighted on line 79 where its used again. I would like to change the color of this highlighting on line 79.

I've looked through a large chunk of the options in the color scheme options, but there are so many settings I'd ideally prefer not to try changing every single one..

Does anyone know what this feature is called, so I can find it in the color scheme settings?

[image]

Comment: Are you using a native theme or are you using a theme plugin like MaterialUI or similar?

Comment: See *Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > General*, items "Identifier under caret" and
"Identifier under caret (write)".

Comment: I'm using the native Darcula theme @squillman

Comment: Thank you @harrymc, this is essentially what I'm looking for. One quick extra question though: If I have my cursor on var on line 78, the var on line 79 highlights according to the color I set. However if I highlight var (as shown in the image in OP) it doesn't use the new color to highlight var on line 79. Any idea what that highlighting is called?

Comment: I don't think there is a separate setting for selected identifier vs identifier under the carret.  Just having your cursor on the identifier on line 78 should highlight the instance on line 79 whether or not your have the full identifier selected on line 78.  The only other setting is the highlight color for search result, but it doesn't sound like this is what you're doing.

Comment: @Addison: I don't think there is an accepted name for it. Each product has different names. I added an answer, if this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colors can be defined via
*Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > General*.

The items concerned are "Identifier under caret" and
"Identifier under caret (write)".